# Messages.app not responding

Tags: macos, messages

My Messages decided to stop responding.

Complete lockout.

The only way to kill it is in the Activity Monitor with Force Quit.

It consumes 100% of the CPU and is not responsive.

[image: messages]

The Force Quit generates a long report to be send to Apple (done that).

Somehow I do not expect Apple to respond to me, but some of you here might.

The Console report shows this:

```
6/17/14 20:07:50.000 kernel[0]: process Messages[6475] thread 409143 caught burning CPU! It used more than 50% CPU (Actual recent usage: 99%) over 180 seconds. thread lifetime cpu usage 90.036317 seconds, (88.239220 user, 1.797097 system) ledger info: balance: 90000243595 credit: 90000243595 debit: 0 limit: 90000000000 (50%) period: 180000000000 time since last refill (ns): 90733220937 
6/17/14 20:07:50.781 ReportCrash[6487]: Invoking spindump for pid=6475 thread=409143 percent_cpu=99 duration=91 because of excessive cpu utilization
6/17/14 20:07:51.766 spindump[6488]: Saved cpu_resource.spin report for Messages version 8.0 (4226) to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Messages_2014-06-17-200751_kelly.cpu_resource.spin
6/17/14 20:08:12.070 com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[138]: (com.apple.iChat.24672[6475]) Exited: Terminated: 15
6/17/14 20:08:19.483 spindump[6492]: Saved hang report for Messages version 8.0 (4226) to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Messages_2014-06-17-200819_kelly.hang
6/17/14 20:09:08.354 SubmitDiagInfo[6519]: Running in single report mode to submit: file:///Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Messages_2014-06-17-200819_kelly.hang
6/17/14 20:09:14.032 SubmitDiagInfo[6519]: Submitted hang report: file:///Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Messages_2014-06-17-200819_kelly.hang
6/17/14 20:09:25.669 Messages[6523]: Chat history path /Users/buscar/Library/Containers/com.apple.iChat/Data/Library/Messages/Archive Status: 0 totalExpected: 0 countProcessed: 0, forcing an import.
6/17/14 20:10:23.840 Finder[150]: CGSCopyDisplayUUID: Invalid display 0x44105d81
6/17/14 20:10:27.898 Console[6528]: setPresentationOptions called with NSApplicationPresentationFullScreen when there is no visible fullscreen window; this call will be ignored.
6/17/14 20:11:07.000 kernel[0]: process Messages[6523] thread 411156 caught burning CPU! It used more than 50% CPU (Actual recent usage: 88%) over 180 seconds. thread lifetime cpu usage 90.062022 seconds, (88.395516 user, 1.666506 system) ledger info: balance: 90006160672 credit: 90006160672 debit: 0 limit: 90000000000 (50%) period: 180000000000 time since last refill (ns): 101728641163 
6/17/14 20:11:07.333 ReportCrash[6535]: Invoking spindump for pid=6523 thread=411156 percent_cpu=88 duration=103 because of excessive cpu utilization
6/17/14 20:11:08.385 spindump[6536]: Saved cpu_resource.spin report for Messages version 8.0 (4226) to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Messages_2014-06-17-201108_kelly.cpu_resource.spin
6/17/14 20:11:11.478 Finder[150]: CGSCopyDisplayUUID: Invalid display 0x44105d81
```

I tried [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4724336) but did not help.

On MBA 10.9.3

Update: The Diagnostic report does not fit in here :(

Maximum 30000 allowed, the reports is 108181 ?

Comment: Can you post the `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Messages_2014-06-17-201108_kelly.cpu_resource.spin`?

Comment: @GeorgeGarside I can but it is like 3 pages long, tell me what you looking for so I can extract it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem Solved

Thanks to [Ralph Johns (UK)Ferndown UK](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4659901)

(root cause remains Unknown.)

I followed these instructions:

1. Go to `~/Library/Preferences`
2. Delete `com.apple.ichat.plist`

Comment: Where did you find the ~/Library/Preferences?